Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop is failing to respond to Plex requests consistently - Any Suggestions?
I am having issues with my new home server. I've installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS desktop version, brand new mini PC (beelink S12). All I use it for is Plex and a few minor things via desktop, so I want the gui (Hence why I downloaded the GUI version). I've installed Plex Media Server, all was well and good, but after some time (say 8 hours), Plex cannot find the server.
Note: I CAN get it back up and running, usually by fiddling with the OS and things or connecting to something and THEN Plex will start working, but I'd really like to ALWAYS respond and be able to use it consistently without intervention.
When the issue happens, it's like ping to the IP address that's hosting Plex isn't responding, and the port isn't responding when I try from another machine. To my knowledge, the system should ALWAYS be listening and ALWAYS respond on the same network. Note that when I do walk away for five minutes, it does make me log back in to OS, but it is literally the only account and generally services should still be running after.
Basically, I can boil it down to 3 possibilities.. the machine is either going to sleep, the router isn't getting the requests to the device, or I'm missing services on Ubuntu that keep it up (ie. maybe install the server version instead of the desktop version).
Here is what I've done so far...

Started with Windows machine - Installed Ubuntu on brand new mini server (all new hardware) - same issue
I've set Ubuntu (and Windows) to NEVER go to sleep
I've done countless uninstalls/re-installs/updates of Plex
I've given it a static IP address (reserved it on the router)
I happened to be switching ISPs and had a new router, so I tried an entirely new router
I've tried using the Caffiene app in Ubuntu to make sure it never sleeps
Power Options, I've set to high performance

I'm burnt out on things to try/ideas. Any advice would be appreciated. Is there anything I can see on the router that would tell me the packets aren't making it? Should I do some sort of packet trace (if so, how)? Are there services I may be missing in Ubuntu that I can download to make it more "Server" friendly, instead of "Desktop"? Is there a cronjob I can run every few minutes to keep it up and responding?
All and any inputs are appreciated!
